# How do I debug code in a separate project (in same solution) that a Blazor app references?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, blazor, visual-studio-debugging, blazor-client-side

I'm trying to port my console app over to a Blazor app. Everything worked fine inside the console type project, but it's not inside the Blazor project so I'm trying to troubleshoot. The app calls some things from a separate "class library" type project within the same solution.

The troubleshooting process itself is having issues of its own though. After a little bit of confusion I realized that the breakpoints set inside the referenced class library type project's code are not being hit.

Checking to console, I see it gives the error:

`L: Unable to insert breakpoint at FtxApi.FtxWebSocketApi/<Test>d__5:MoveNext ():15`

Is there anything I need to do (project settings or something) for the debugger to hit these? Or is it not supported at the moment?

Right now I'm just using a lot of `Console.Writeline` sort of as a workaround/replacement. And I noticed that the `Console.Writeline`s inside the referenced class library type project are being called.. but only up to a certain method call that comes from a third party package. Execution seems to return from that point (nothing is called after it). Not sure what's going wrong there - more troubleshooting is needed, which brings us back to the breakpoints not firing (ideally I'd be able to make use of them).

I understand Blazor is new (and I'm an absolute beginner at using it), so not everything needs or is going to be perfect. I'm asking about the breakpoints kind of out of curiosity (I'd like to get them working but no big deal otherwise).

What I'd really like some insight into is: What might be going on with the code seemingly stopping execution / returning at that one particular method call? The method I'm calling is `WebSocket.Open()`, from the package [WebSocket4Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocket4Net/). As mentioned above, I've tested this before (in a Console app) and it worked fine, so I'm guessing it's somehow related to Blazor which I'm unfamiliar with. I'm unsure how to get any more info to help debug this problem. Any help appreciated.

**Edit:**

I managed to find a solution to my problem without the use of debugging tools like breakpoints and such (I just used Console.Writeline a lot). I guess Blazor does not support some websocket implementations or something, because I found this error: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform. blazor.webassembly.js:1   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket` coming from `websocket.Open()`. I managed to get it working by implementing System.Net.Websockets instead, similar to [this](https://fuqua.io/blog/2020/02/native-websockets-with-blazor-webassembly/). Though my troubleshooting is over (for now), I'm still wondering if it's somehow possible to use breakpoints inside other referenced projects.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 solutions:

Solution 1: Right-click at Solution, choose `Properties`, choose `Common Properties`, Choose `Multiple startup project`, choose Action `Start` for `Foo.Client`, `Foo.Server`, `Foo.Shared` . Something like this

[image]

See https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2015/04/07/debug-multiple-projects-at-the-same-time-in-visual-studio

Solution 2: Compile `SharedProject`, attacht PDB for debugging.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-an-executable-not-part-of-a-visual-studio-solution?view=vs-2019

Comment: Hmm, maybe I've misunderstood but I think these solutions are not for my particular problem. The `SharedProject` I mention was just placeholder project referring to Visual Studio's actual [shared project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows#what-is-a-shared-project) type. I think this can be considered as if the Blazor project were to directly have the code (i.e. just copied inside). So perhaps the `SharedProject` is not the cause of the problem, but rather something to do with Blazor in particular?

Comment: Can't recall I've ever tried using breakpoints in a Shared Project before though, so maybe I'll try that and see (i.e. it might not have to do with Blazor). I might also need to take a step back and think about this for a bit to make sure what I'm saying actually makes sense. Guess I can try running the code in a different (non-console and non-Blazor) project and see if it encounters the same problem.

Comment: Oh my bad I just realized it's actually a "class library" type project I'm referencing (not a shared project). I guess the same ideas still apply though.

Comment: I'm still convinced it's something to do with Blazor or my Blazor project (or something else I've not thought of / mentioned yet). Messed around with it a bit and it's what I keep coming back to.